# np.exp much slower than np.e?

Tags: python, numpy, optimization

```
In [49]: timeit.timeit("np.exp(100)", setup="import numpy as np")
Out[49]: 1.700455904006958

In [50]: timeit.timeit("np.e**100", setup="import numpy as np")
Out[50]: 0.16629505157470703
```

Is there any reason that using the CPython implementation of np.e**100 is that much slower than using the numpy version? Shouldn't the numpy version be faster as it is pushed down to C code?

Comment: I believe the former is using techniques to approximate the analytical exponential function (possibly considering the complex plane as well). The latter is probably using a floating point approximation which would understandably be faster.

Comment: I would like to thank you for this post ! I would have never thought to test np.e** instead of np.exp and that happened to decrease brutally my computation times !

Comment: "Shouldn't the numpy version be faster as it is pushed down to C code?" - the exponentiation gets computed in C code either way. NumPy can push *loops* down to C code, when you let it operate on whole arrays at once, but you're giving it a scalar.

Answer (score 8):

One obvious reason is that `np.exp` is set up to handle arrays, and there's probably a bit of overhead involved there in terms of figuring out the type/dimensions of the input. Try out cases like these, and you might see the difference reduce or vanish:

```
timeit.timeit("np.exp(x)", 
              setup="import numpy as np; x = np.array([99, 100, 101])")
# This actually seems to be faster than just calculating
#   it for a single value
Out[7]: 1.0747020244598389

timeit.timeit("[np.e**n for n in x]", 
              setup="import numpy as np; x = [99, 100, 101]")
Out[8]: 0.7991611957550049
```

Answer (score 2):

I would like to point out that `np.exp` is faster than `np.e` when you give it arrays. I tested this with numpy version 1.22 and Python 3.9.

The exact speedup you get may depend on your architecture. I tested it on a modern 32-threaded AMD cpu.

For real-valued data, `np.exp` is roughly 5 times faster than `np.e`. For complex-valued data, the factor is closer to 2.

Real-valued arrays:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("np.e**x", setup="import numpy as np; x = np.random.random(size=(10,10))")
2.7911060999904294
>>> timeit.timeit("np.exp(x)",setup="import numpy as np; x = np.random.random(size=(10,10))")
0.606489199999487
```

Complex-valued arrays:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("np.e**x", setup="import numpy as np; x = 1j*np.random.random(size=(10,10))")
7.959791200002655
>>> timeit.timeit("np.exp(x)", setup="import numpy as np; x = 1j*np.random.random(size=(10,10))")
3.637887800025055
```

Answer (score 0):

Gotta be function call overhead etc. Even `np.exp(0)` is equally slow, and that shouldn't actually compute anything.

```
>>> timeit.timeit("np.exp(100)", setup="import numpy as np")
2.8452274883430846
>>> timeit.timeit("np.exp(0)", setup="import numpy as np")
2.836107299807054
```

Comment: Why do you think that `exp(0)` would naturally be faster to compute than `exp(100)`? Unless there's code to specifically check for an input of `0`, which would slow down every single call.

Comment: @MarkRansom Hmm, admittedly I don't know how it's implemented and I couldn't find it in numpy or Python now, I only found [this in C](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/e_exp.c;h=4eb1bdc657ed53f14abf4f6333732babe7d38e9b;hb=HEAD#l109), which does look like such special treatment.

Comment: @MarkRansom Though what I was thinking was not such special treatment but rather a natural early stop, like the summands of the power series being 0 right after the initial 1 and thus the calculating loop stopping right away there. Again, I admit I don't know how it's actually calculated, and if I'm wrong and the value of the exponent doesn't matter for the speed of the calculation, please educate me :-). In particular, if you can point me to the actual implementation or tell me how it's calculated, I'd appreciate that.

Comment: @MarkRansom Ok I did find an actual calculation [elsewhere](http://www.netlib.org/fdlibm/e_exp.c) and there's no loop but a fixed t*(P1+t*(P2+t*(P3+t*(P4+t*P5)))). But even there I see a special case treatment that I think will prevent the calculation if the exponent is zero.